# Upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.1 CLI Command Error

Tags: magento2, cli, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.1

When upgrading from Magento CE 2.2.6 to Magento CE 2.3.1, I am following the command line upgrade as explained [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html). All was well and the commands ran just as they should have until I ran the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Upon running this command I am seeing the following error:

[image: Error]

Please advise me on how I can go about solving this error.

Comment: Do you have any extensions ? If yes how many ? and dotmailer is there ?

Comment: Yes; following is the output I get when I run php bin/magento module:status .         List of enabled modules:
MSP_ReCaptcha
MSP_TwoFactorAuth
MageMojo_Cron
Amazon_Core
Klarna_Core
Amazon_Login
Amazon_Payment
Dotdigitalgroup_Email
Nuethic_DuplicateFix
Nuethic_ProductSuccess
Nuethic_ScriptInjector
RocketWeb_ShoppingFeeds
RocketWeb_ShoppingFeedsGoogle
ShipWorks_Module
Signifyd_Connect
Smartwave_Core
Smartwave_Filterproducts
Smartwave_Megamenu
Smartwave_Porto
Smartwave_Socialfeeds
Temando_Shipping
Vertex_Tax
WebShopApps_MatrixRate